# How to display contents of array in twig

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

I've spent the last 3 days looking for a solution to this :/

I have a function that loops through contents of a directory:

I was putting something together but it had a ton of for loops, so I searched online and found something similar that I was able to modify to fit what I needed:

```
   require_once "library/Twig/Autoloader.php";
  Twig_Autoloader::register();

  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('views/');
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

$dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/';

  function fileList($dir){
     global $files;
     $files = scandir($dir);
      foreach($files as $file){
          if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
              if(is_dir($dir . $file)){
                 fileList($dir . $file);
               }
          }
      }
  };

  fileList($dir);
```

Then I have this:

```
  echo $twig->render('home.twig', array('file' => $files, 'dir' => $dir));
```

and in my home.twig file I have this:

```
      <ol>
        {% for key, files in file %}
           <li>{{file[key]}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ol>
```

What I'm trying to do is display the contents on $files using twig on the page, but I cannot wrap my head around it. pls help?

It's weird, I noticed that when I add `global $files;` inside the function it outputs only the contents of the first directory and stops. can't figure out why it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly reworked version of the function that will recurse into subfolders and list everything in a single, flat array:

```
function fileList($dir, &$files = array()){

    $this_dir = scandir($dir);

    foreach($this_dir as $file){
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir . $file)){
                fileList($dir.$file.'/', $files);
            } else {
                $files[] = $dir . $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a short example of function usage:

```
$dir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/';
fileList($dir, $files);
echo '<h2>Scanning Directory: '.$dir.'</h2>'; //These two lines are
echo '<pre>'.print_r($files, true).'</pre>'; //just to see the results
```

Then in the twig output you'll only need a simple loop to display it.

```
  <ol>
    {% for key, files in file %}
        <li>{{file[key]}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>
```

Comment: ohh awesome!! that makes more sense. I tried your suggestion and it works, but only for the first set of files, the part of the loop where it checks if it's a directory doesn't run for some weird reason

Comment: ok, so I think that the reason why `is_dir()` is not running is because `$files` is an array and it's not looping through it..

Comment: I think you just need `if(is_dir($dir . '/' . $file)){`

Comment: hmmm, when I `echo $dir . '/' . $file;` I get `//Array` at the end of the line instead of the name of the file. when I do `echo $dir .  $file[3];` I get the file path

Comment: Cool, does that solve the recursion problem and display all the files then?  I assume you're using that recursive function because you want to display files in subfolders as well right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to display all of the files in the directory, not just $file[3]